# How to enable scroll bar when viewing a web page in Mobile Device mode?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile-development

In Chrome (119.0.6045.124 (Official Build) (64-bit) Windows), when I enable Mobile View to show my web page as it would be rendered on a mobile device, there is no way to see the entire device viewport on the screen without zooming out.

How can I enable a scroll bar to allow me to scroll the view of the device viewport?  I am NOT asking how to enable scrolling **within** the device viewport.

In Firefox, for example, in Mobile Preview mode, there is a scrollbar on the far right side of the screen which allows the simulated mobile device viewport to be scrolled up and down.  This scrollbar does not affect the actual web page content.

How can I enable this feature in Chrome?